# Maven assembly plugin missing jmxtools

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

For some reason maven assembly:single throws the error below. But maven-assembly-plugin dependency tree doesn't show the jmxtools. maven central doesn't have the jar file. http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/jdmk/jmxtools/1.2.1/ 
I am perplexed, what am I missing ? Any help is appreciated.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:3.1.0:single (ci) on project extracense: Failed to create assembly: Error creating assembly archive ci: C:\Users\v493289\.m2\repository\com\sun\jdmk\jmxtools\1.2.1\jmxtools-1.2.1.jar -> [Help 1]
```

Here is the maven dependency tree.

```
[INFO] \- org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.maven:maven-plugin-api:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-plexus:jar:1.4.2:compile
[INFO]    |     \- org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-inject-bean:jar:1.4.2:compile
[INFO]    |        \- org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:noaop:2.1.7:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.maven:maven-core:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-settings-builder:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-repository-metadata:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-model-builder:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-aether-provider:jar:3.0:runtime
[INFO]    |  +- org.sonatype.aether:aether-impl:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.sonatype.aether:aether-spi:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.sonatype.aether:aether-api:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.sonatype.aether:aether-util:jar:1.7:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-classworlds:jar:2.2.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-component-annotations:jar:1.5.5:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-sec-dispatcher:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO]    |     \- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-cipher:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.maven:maven-model:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.maven.shared:maven-common-artifact-filters:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-utils:jar:3.1.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.maven.shared:maven-artifact-transfer:jar:0.9.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-interpolation:jar:1.24:compile
[INFO]    +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-archiver:jar:3.5:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.iq80.snappy:snappy:jar:0.4:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.6:runtime
[INFO]    +- org.apache.maven.shared:file-management:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.maven.shared:maven-shared-io:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.maven:maven-compat:jar:3.0:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-provider-api:jar:2.10:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.maven.shared:maven-filtering:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.sonatype.plexus:plexus-build-api:jar:0.0.7:compile
[INFO]    +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-io:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.maven:maven-archiver:jar:3.2.0:compile
[INFO]    \- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:3.1.0:compile
```

Comment: I bet there are more error/warnings in the output...

Comment: Thankyou for the reply. I gave up on this and configured the project to use your plugin. Thank you for MultiEnv Maven plugin.